# How to mock object created by spring application context using Mockito for Unit Test coverage?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, applicationcontext

Application scenario:
TaskScheduler is triggered at regular cron interval. Each scheduler job will create multiple runnable threads. Each thread will perform the ETL process.

```
public class LoadTask {

    private static final AuditLogService AUDIT_LOG_SERVICE = 
    ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext().getBean("auditLogService", AuditLogService.class);

    public void perform(ETLDetailsDTO etlDetailsDTO) {
       // Business logic
       AUDIT_LOG_SERVICE.save(AuditLogBuilder.buildSuccessAuditLog())
   }
}
```

AuditLogService is a Service annotated spring managed bean.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Getter
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        applicationContext = appContext;
    }
}
```

LoadTask is not and spring managed component, thus I am taking the help of ApplicationContextUtils to get the bean of AuditLogService. The application is working fine. While writing the unit test case of LoadTask, Null Pointer Exception is thrown.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class LoadTaskTest {

@InjectMocks
private LoadTask loadTask;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testPerform() {
    Mockito.when(ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext().getBean("auditLogService", AuditLogService.class)).thenReturn(new AuditLogService());
    loadTask.perform(MockObjectHelper.getETLDetailsDTO());
}
}
```

I am not able to set mock object of AUDIT_LOG_SERVICE and run test case successfully. How to mock or spy ApplicationContextUtils so that LoadTask does not throw any error?

Answer (score 1):

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class LoadTaskTest {

@InjectMocks
private LoadTask loadTask;
@Mock
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
@Mock
private AuditLogService auditLogService;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    new ApplicationContextUtils().setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
}

@Test
public void testPerform() {
    Mockito.when(applicationContext.getBean("auditLogService", AuditLogService.class)).thenReturn(auditLogService);
    loadTask.perform(MockObjectHelper.getETLDetailsDTO());
 }
}
```

Add mockito-inline dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```